# http to https redireaction problem using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, http, redirect, mod-rewrite, https

I have problem with http to https redirection using .htaccess

I use this code on .htaccess

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

I have tested and used before on other servers, and it worked fine

But here on this server it fails, when I try to visit this site (http or https) I doesn't work, it returns following error message:

ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

so.. I begin to test and try different things trying to understand what was  happening.. and finally I found problem (but still did not find solution)

problem is that for some reason %{HTTPS} match to "off" if I use http it matches to off (correct) and if I use https:// it matches to "off" (and that is wrong! it should match to "on".

To be sure that it was the problem I replaced .htaccess content with following

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^aaa.html$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/foo.html?%{HTTPS} [R=301,L]
```

I did that to see value assumed by %{HTTPS}

And when I visit
https://www.example.com/aaa.html I am redirected to

https://www.example.com/foo.hml?off when it should go to

https://www.example.com/foo.hml?on

why %{HTTPS} is off when I visit it using https?

Comment: _"why %{HTTPS} is off when I visit it using https?"_ - could be that your hoster has some kind of proxy setup, so that your requests don't go to your web server immediately. What happens when you check `%{SERVER_POST}` instead?

Comment: I tested "%{SERVER_POST}" it shows empty string...

Comment: Typo, I meant SERVER_PORT.

Comment: @CBroe, %{SERVER_PORT} = 80,  it is 80 still when using https

Comment: Then you should go and ask your server admin, about the specifics of the setup. My guess is that there is some sort of proxy before the web server, that simply passes the requests along via HTTP, even if the request to the proxy was made using HTTPS.